# Как из node.js (node-postgres) достать переменную и использовать ее в нативном js файле?

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql

Подскажите пожалуйста, я использую node.js и node-postgres для получения определенных данных, все подключилось, данные читаются, но только внутри функции. Пример кода:

```
    const {Client} = require('pg');
    const client = new Client({
    user: 'admin',
    host: '172.15.15.111',
    database: 'some_db',
    password: 'password',
    port: 5432
});
client.connect();
client.query('SELECT code, display_name, description FROM core.actions', (err,res) => {
    var pgCode = JSON.stringify(res.rows);
    client.end();
    console.log(pgCode);
});
```

Я пытался использовать внутри `client.query` `module.exports.pgCode = pgCode;`, но у меня ничего не вышло.

Как я могу передать pgCode в другой js файл, либо во внешнюю среду или как глобальную переменную?
Или может есть другой способ получения данных из БД postgres?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как вернуть значение из события или из функции обратного вызова? Или хотя бы дождаться их окончания](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/554290/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8b%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d0%98%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d1%85%d0%be%d1%82%d1%8f-%d0%b1%d1%8b-%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b6)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте babel или typescript для современного импорта/экспорта переменных!
Пример использования с babel

config.js

```
export const config = {
  user: 'admin',
  host: '172.15.15.111',
  database: 'some_db',
  password: 'password',
  port: 5432
}
```

client.js

```
import { config } from './config';
import { Client } from 'pg';
export const client = new Client(config);
client.connect();
```

wrapper.js

```
import { client } from './client';

export async function getDataFromDb(text) {
    const query = client.query(text);
    return data;
}
```

querytest.js

```
import { getDataFromDb } from './wrapper';

(async function() {
    const query = await getDataFromDb(`SELECT * FROM "MYTABLE"`);
    console.log(query.rows);
})();
```